# Collection of audio inside collection of image

Tags: image, symfony, audio

I am looking for a solution to create a gallery of picture and each picture can have multiple audio file (mp3) related to it.

Those collection will be uploaded directly by the user who controller the number of picture and audio file.

Does anyone can guide me to do it the best possible way.

Comment: This is extremely broad. Have you done anything so far? Entities, associations, file upload, many moving parts here

Comment: yes sure i have made my entity with some main filed like title, subtile blabla with image collection, but now i need to modify the image collection so every image need to have a collection of audio file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was very vague so my answer will have to be as well. I'm guessing you are wanting to know how to do this in the database. You should create a table called, for example, "images". Create a second one called "audio" that contains a field named "image_id". Then when you store an image you'll have the ID of the image can then store that in with the audio in the image_id field. You'll have to save the image and audio files in a particular folder (most likely in the "web" folder) and use the database to save the file names so that you can retrieve them. If you set up your entities correctly with relationships, you should be able to easily create a Twig template and gather all the audio for each image with minimal work.

Comment: Thanks i create an collection of ID in my table exposition then i create a table image with 3 field 1 for image 2 for audio (2 audio file for now only) and of course every field is related to exposition ID. That works great for me. But there is one major issue still remain as those image is going to be send to external react application i need to protect them from being viewed if the user does not have a memberhip so from react it is easy but from my symfony backoffice i don't know how to protect and which path should i send